# Tracking direct traffic on a url alias

Tags: google-analytics, alias

I'm looking for help on how to track a url that is being on direct mail pieces, appointment cards, flyers and non digital materials. I've noticed GA will lump all of this traffic into the direct/organic bucket. Is there a way I can track just the alias typed in directly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UTM parameters in querystring (add campaign parameters to URLs) so you can track Custom Campaigns in Google Analytics: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

You can use this tool, Campaign URL Builder: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/

**EDIT**

You can use a shorten URL based on an URL with UTM parameters. For example you can add UTM in querystring like this:

```
prevea.com/pimarycare?utm_source=dem&utm_medium=offline&utm_campaign=flyer
```

The use a tool to generate a shorten url, like this: https://tinyurl.com/

The tool generates an URL like this:

```
tinyurl.com/twr3qlk
```

In the flyer you should be use that URL.

Try to entered the URL *tinyurl.com/twr3qlk* in browser bar, you can see a redirect to your desiderated UTL with UTM parameters.

Comment: Hi Michele,

Sounds great in theory. However, these urls will not be used digitally. If our mailer says visit prevea.com/pimarycare, how can I get the number of visits on that specific direct alias? To my understanding adding a UTM, this will only work if used in a digital campaign. Am I correct?

Thanks,

Comment: I add more detail on my answer. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can segment your sessions by Landing Page:

[image]